# Shorthand javascript regex .replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, shorthand

I was trying to write some code-golf in which I used javascript's regex `.replace()` method and as the second parameter I passed an anonymous function like so `.replace(/(exp)/,function(x){return x.toUpperCase();})` which, as I understand, is the way it needs to be done if u are using the matched sub-string to determine what to replace.

At least thats what I understood [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Is there a shorter way to do this? Specifically eliminating `function(x){return` and `;}`?

I saw this code that has a replace without a function call `.replace(/([\[\]])/g, '\\$1');`.

Comment: The code you saw will only replace with what was matched in the replace regex pattern. The anonymous function you passed is converting that match to uppercase. You can safely use `.replace(/([\[\]])/g, '\\$1')` to prepend a backslash to square brackets.

Comment: however is there a way to do what i want without a anonymous function?

Comment: You cannot use a function onto a replace without an anonymous function.

Comment: What's the problem behind your question? Readability?

Comment: @DioF no, i want to see if i can get it shorter.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight If it's an ES2015 answer `.replace(/(exp)/, ${x.toUpperCase()}`) world work using template strings

Answer (score -2):

Technically you can simplify the code, by assigning the function to a variable:

```
<script>
var u = function(x) {
    return x.toUpperCase();   
}
</script>
```

Then use the variable instead of the anonymous function:

```
str.replace(/(exp)/, u);
```

but it *moves* the code rather than *eliminates* it. Still, it achieves the desired brevity.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qr2BJ/11006/)